# How to get nvarchar data from SQL Server database

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, getstring

I'd like to get some values from `nvarchar` column (SQL Server database). My code looks like below:

```
Dim value1 As String

Dim con2 As New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
con2.ConnectionString = "data source=AAA;initial catalog=DWH;integrated security=SSPI;"

con2.Open()

Dim retrieveGSFdata As New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
retrieveGSFdata.Connection = con2
retrieveGSFdata.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM table1"

Dim myGSFdataReader as System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader
myGSFdataReader = retrieveGSFdata.ExecuteReader()

Dim iteratorGSF As Integer
iteratorGSF = 0

while(myGSFdataReader.read())

    Select Case iteratorGSF
      case 0:
        if myGSFdataReader.IsDBNull(4)
           value1 = 0
        else
           value1 = myGSFdataReader.GetString(4)
        end if
    End Select  

    iteratorGSF = iteratorGSF + 1

End while

myGSFdataReader.Close()
con2.Close()
```

It works fine only when there are numeric values in the column. But in this column are stored variable characters values and this types of values are not being displayed on the page. I don't know what is the reason.

I've tried to use `getValue.ToString` instead of `getString` but it doesn't work either.

I'd be grateful for your help.

Comment: You say *SQL* (Structured Query Language), but you really mean **SQL Server** (the MIcrosoft database product) - right?

Comment: Also: can you tell us what columns that `table1` has (name and their datatype) and show us how you're trying to read out a `nvarchar` column? Also: you say *it did not work* - did you get an error? If so: **WHAT** exact error did you get ?

Comment: @marc_s I think that is safe to assume since he's using the SqlClient namespace, but good point.

Comment: In what way does it not work?  Do you get exceptions, or null values, or wrong values, or what?  What happened when you called ToString instead of GetString?

Comment: can you give some sample data and your table structure

Comment: @Konza The reason we are all asking you for the additional information is because there is nothing wrong syntactically with when you are doing.  Calling DataReader.GetString and storing the result in a string variable is precisely how you should be reading an nvarchar column.  So, if it's not working, it due to something else.  Since we don't have your database to connect to, we can't reproduce the problem, so if you want us to help you, you are going to have to provide us with more details.

Comment: Yes I mean of course SQL Server.
Column is named "displayedString" and has datatype nvarchar(150).

In this column are stored descriptions of some operations (it is simple text containing detailed information as data, city etc.)

I'm trying to display this values in aspx page using
    <script type="text/javascript">document.write(<%= displayedStringMaxSMS %>)</script>

I don't get any error if in the column there is text - the text is just not being displayed. When I insert to the column numeric values - numbers appears on aspx page.

Comment: @Konza Have you traced through it to verify that the value1 variable is really empty after executing the `value1 = myGSFdataReader.GetString(4)` line?  If it's not displaying properly, it could be a problem with that code rather the part where you are reading it.

Comment: Yes you're right - the problem is with reading this values.
Probably I should change script type in aspx code.

Comment: From ASPX code I removed this part of code: <script type="text/javascript">document.write()</script>, so i left only:
<%= value1 %> and now it works :)

Thank you guys so much for your help!

Comment: @Konza Then please post that as an answer and accept it so others know this has been resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Try

value1 = myGSFdataReader.GetValue(4)

Or

value1 = CStr(myGSFdataReader.GetValue(4))

Comment: It gives the same result as before. When I insert to the column value "555aaa" on the aspx page the value doesn't appear, and when I insert "555" - the number is being displayed.

Comment: when you debug, what is assigned to value1.  You need to see if value1 is being assigned correctly before passed to the aspx page